# Youtube-dl viewster playlist language selection

Tags: language, playlists, youtube-dl

I am trying to download a playlist (http://www.viewster.com/serie/1291-19458-000/) using youtube-dl but If I download `-f best` it gives me a 720p video in japanese dub with Spanish or French subtitles most of the time but what I want is japanese dub with english subtitles. Youtube-dl does not list any video language selection command in it's help (only for subtitles), so idk if there's some sort of undocumented one.

I then ran `-F` and I saw that Every episode comes in 4 different languages (en, ja-en, ja-fr, ja-es), 6 resolutions (234p, ..., 720p) and 3 streaming methods (hls, http, hds) + audio only. `ja-en-http-XXXX` for example, where XXXX is the tbr of the video in kbit/s.

I tried using the subtitle language option but it didn't work because the subs are part of the encoded video.

Is there any way to download the wanted language without manually finding out the tbr and putting it in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f best'[format_id^=ja-en-http]'`

`^=` means "begins with"; you could also do it with `*=` ("contains")